# Model class is not filled with input values after submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have following code and the problem is that values I am sending from the form are stored in additional class in model and after submit the values are NULL in controller model.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Territory(TerritoryVM m)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            !!! m.TerritoryFormItem IS NULL !!!
        }
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public class TerritoryVM
{
    public TerritoryVM()
    {
    }

    public TerritoryFormItem TerritoryFormItem;
}
```

**Class used in model:**

```
public class TerritoryFormItem
{
    [Required, DisplayName("Territory Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.TerritoryFormItem.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TerritoryFormItem.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: Because `TerritoryFormItem` is a field, not a property and the `DefaultModelBinder` only binds properties. Change it to `public TerritoryFormItem TerritoryFormItem { get; set; }`

Comment: Seriously, you accepted that answer?

Comment: Stephen: yes because in the answer was "link" to your comment which solved my problem, but I cannot accept comment, only answer.. anyway thank you a lot.

Comment: Please do not accept bad answers. It just misleads other user who come across this. The question is marked as duplicate so there is no need to accept anything (and I deleted the reference to my name - I wont be associated with that nonsense)

Answer (score 0):

Model binding is wrong, which means data type doesn't match.

The use of ViewModel is weird in your code. Should it be a similar class to Model class, rather than having cascading class in ViewModel...

I am sure you can do this, but it's not straight forward at all.